# app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug error when I am using a particular jar's method otherwise working fine

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, testng

Hi I am using appium with android studio

When I use testng jar file then it throws following error

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test2 {

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {

        System.out.println("seyup");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1()  {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
     java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {@C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication23\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args328085686608198817}
```

When I use JUnit jar file then it works fine, with the same script

```
   package com.example.admin.myapplication2;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;


    public class Test2 {

        @Before
        public void setUp() {

            System.out.println("seyup");
        }

        @Test
        public void test1()  {

            System.out.println("first");
        }
    }
```

That's my graddle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myapplication2"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
        android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

            jumboMode = true
        }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.0.0'
    //    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
    compile files('libs/java-client-4.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar')
    //compile files('libs/testng-6.0.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/testng-6.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar')
    implementation files('libs/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xalan-2.7.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/websocket-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
    implementation files('libs/htmlunit-2.26.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-remote-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jetty-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/neko-htmlunit-2.25.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-safari-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-chrome-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-api-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/serializer-2.7.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/cssparser-0.9.22.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-opera-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-firefox-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/htmlunit-driver-2.26.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-edge-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-ie-driver-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jetty-http-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/selenium-support-3.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sac-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-21.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/websocket-api-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
    implementation files('libs/htmlunit-core-js-2.26.jar')
    implementation files('libs/websocket-common-9.4.3.v20170317.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar')
    implementation files('libs/testng-6.0.1.jar')

}
```

I am stuck here and any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem?